# Why do fewer developers use Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi

This is a non technical question.

I am a Delphi developer so I have met many developers from the community , but only a few have said they know a programming IDE called Delphi and only a very very few know Delphi. I am very comfortable with Delphi and I always prefer Delphi for windows development(but I know many developers on the internet eg: YOU). Why isn't Delphi as famous as it was during the Borland era?

Comment: Once you work with MS products you can not live with products of others, starting from the IDE the VS since 2003 is great and fantastic, documentation is well organized and rich. That what crossed my mind for now, I worked on XBuilder and I just did not like it.

Comment: @A_Nablsi, that's not true, I have been using MS IDE and languages before Delphi and still use them, but they can't beat Delphi in many areas, specially in performance, productivity and deployment,but I agree with Documentation.

Comment: Mohammed Nasman you are corret delphi is good but why dont others use this

Comment: Mostly because the bad marketing at Borland days, they also never put a good investment on Delphi which make it not visible like other tools, now things has changed, new version of Delphi for 64bit and Mac OS on horizon, this will make Delphi the best tool for native cross platform.

Comment: I work in a company in Germany and there are 9 other Delphi programmers here, who are very professional. We use Delphi because the app we develope is started by Delphi about 12 years ago and we still support it and everyday it becomes bigger. I love Delphi but it has a problem: It has become old in mind of others because of Borland bad marketing as Nasman mensioned. So the companies decide to switch to C# for example. I hope someday Embarcadero could bring it at top, because otherwise at least we 10 programmers in this company could not find another job easily, if our company would bankrupt.